# Using elements for multiple funcitons

Tags: javascript

As a beginner for javascript, I'm having some difficulties to build functions so that multiple functions use the same element on a page. The purpose of the function is to calculate and display a value based on the input of a user.

The function looks like this:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById("n182849949").onblur = function () {
  reSumText1();
};
document.getElementById("n182849950").onblur = function () {
  reSumText1();
};
document.getElementById("n182849951").onblur = function () {
  reSumText1();
};
document.getElementById("n182849952").onblur = function () {
  reSumText1();
};

function Tonumber(numX) {
  return Number(numX.replace(".", "").replace(" ", "").replace(",", "."));
}

function reSumText1() {
  var num1 = Tonumber(document.getElementById("n182849949").value);
  var num2 = Tonumber(document.getElementById("n182849950").value);
  var num3 = Tonumber(document.getElementById("n182849951").value);
  var num4 = Tonumber(document.getElementById("n182849952").value);
  var sum2 = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4;
  var sum3 = sum2.toLocaleString("de-DE");
  document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = sum3;
}
</script>
```

The function works as intended, but as soon as there is another function using one of the elements, only one is working:

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById("n182853134").onblur = function () {
  reSumText2();
};
document.getElementById("n182853151").onblur = function () {
  reSumText2();
};
document.getElementById("n182853118").onblur = function () {
  reSumText2();
};
document.getElementById("n182849952").onblur = function () {
  reSumText2();
};

function Tonumber(numX) {
  return Number(numX.replace(".", "").replace(" ", "").replace(",", "."));
}

function reSumText2() {
  var num1 = Tonumber(document.getElementById("n182853134").value);
  var num2 = Tonumber(document.getElementById("n182853151").value);
  var num3 = Tonumber(document.getElementById("n182853118").value);
  var num4 = Tonumber(document.getElementById("n182849952").value);
  var sum2 = num1 + num2 + num3 + num4;
  var sum3 = sum2.toLocaleString("de-DE");
  document.getElementById("2").innerHTML = sum3;
}
</script>
```

Both of the functions "reSumText1" and "reSumText2" work separately, but not together on the same page, since they both use the element n182849952. Is there a way to work around?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by *"...two functions use the same element..."*? Also, *"e. g. "n18284995""* You don't have *any* element in your question with that ID.

Comment: well, that's the point of setting an html element with an `id`, that it's **unique**.. on the flip side, setting `class` to an element makes it possible to have several elements with that `class` like `document.getElementsByClassName(className)[someIndex]`

Comment: You are registering the blur event for `n182849952` only once. Then what is the issue here?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Lets  say i'm using the same function with three different elements, but use on which I am already using in the first function.

Comment: I didn't also understand what you mean by "...two functions use the same element..."? but if its a threading problem, try the use setTimeOut( () => reSumText1() , 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each element only has one `onBlur` method. You are overwriting the `onBlur` method in both places, so the second script erases the `onBlur` method you assigned in the first. You need to assign both functions at the same time.

Like this:

```js
document.getElementById("n182849949").onblur = function () {
  reSumText1();
  reSumText2();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if I misunderstood, but I believe that only the second function looks like it's running because they're both setting the innerHTML value of the HTML element in question. So the first function *is* running, but the second one is just overwriting it so fast that you can't tell.

Again, if I misunderstood the question, please let me know, so I can edit my answer.